# Collision check loop stops looping after enemy is spawned

Tags: javascript, for-loop, collision-detection

So I have been making this little shooter game with javascript and I have ran to a problem I cant figure out.

I have a collision check which checks if any alive enemy collides with the player or a bullet using a for loop. The loop runs fine until I spawn an enemy.

In the beginning of the for loop you can see `console.log`, it logs numbers only ti­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­ll the first alive enemy's `index`. For example if `enemies[4]` is alive and no other enemies with `index` before that are alive, it keeps logging `0, 1, 2, 3` and `4`. If I then kill all the enemies the loop runs full 50 times again (which is the length of the array) until an enemy spawns.­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

```
checkCollision: function(){
    function calculate(enemy, other){
        var r = enemy.r + other.r;
        var dx = enemy.posX - other.posX;
        var dy = enemy.posY - other.posY;
        var d = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
        if(r > d){
            enemy.alive = false;
            other.alive = false;
            return true;
            }
        return false;­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
    }
    for (var i = 0, max = this.enemies.length; i < max; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        if(this.e­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­nemies[i].alive){
            if(calculate(this.enemies[i], this.player)){
                continue;
            }
            for (var i = 0, max = this.player.weapon.bullets.length; i < max; i++){
                if(this.player.weapon.bullets[i].alive){
                    if(calculate(this.enemies[i], this.player.weapon.bullets[i])){
                        break;­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
                    }
                }­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
            }
        }
    }    ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
}
```

Here is a little visualization:

```
[0] = !alive
[1] = alive
[2] = !alive
[3] = alive
[4] = alive
```

Now the for loop would run only 2 times, therefore not checking the collision for 3 and 4, which is what i want it to do.

Comment: Could you explain how you spawn an enemy, and explain more the bug? I am not even sure if there is an unintended behaviour or an error message...

Comment: There is a timer and when it reaches spawn rate limit a spawn function is called which sets the first non-alive enemy's alive-boolean to true and the game continues updating that enemy. I want the collsion check to check collision between all alive objects but it doesnt due to that bug. Console doesnt say any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a loop, which loops over all enemies, but checks only one enemy at a time and only against the `player`, not against each other.

So try something like:

```
    for (var i = 0, max = this.enemies.length; i < max; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, max = this.enemies.length; j < max; j++) {
            if(calculate(this.enemies[i], this.enemies[j]){
                doSomething();
            }
        }
    }
    // Don't forget the player.
```

---

In case you are interested, there is a quite good [HTML5 Game Development](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs255/) course which teaches you how to use an open source physics engine, which takes care of those things.

While looking for a job, I made a small version of Mario, using that open source project, and the info from that course. You can see the game on [my website](http://ramzikahil.herokuapp.com/) under "projects".

---

---

**Edit**

So after your example I understood your question. You are reusing the `i` and `max` variables in the inner loop about bullets. So if the inner loop finishes, the outer loop will also terminate as they both check `i < max`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what i want is that enemies can collide only with the player and its bullets.

Comment: Oh my god how come i did not see this. Thank you a lot! I got it working perfectly now.